# Amazon rds: Arabic character converted to ??? after committing

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, multilingual, amazon-rds

I am facing issue while storing Arabic character on Amazon rds,i am using mysql, On local server character-set-server is utf8 which support Arabic but for amazon RDS  it is latin1,which i can't change,although i have converted all other instances of character-set to utf8 but still m facing issue.Can any one help me in solving this issue,Local server variable list [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIKL4.png)
Amazon server variable list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkUml.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a mysql connector then,

I believe you may have missed to set collation to utf8-general-ci for
Db from properties of database chose alter then select collation.
Table from properties of database chose alter then select collation.
for Column as well.

This may do the trick.